# Tensorflow cannot compute Addv2 as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but it is a float tensor [Op:Addv]

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Error message:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: cannot
>   compute AddV2 as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double
>   tensor but is a float tensor [Op:AddV2]

In my code I create a tensorflow distribution MixtureSameFamily object and use the output of my network as parameters. However when I try to calculate the probability across a range of values in order to generate the probability density function, I receive this error.

My code:

```
gm = tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
    mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(probs=alphas),
    components_distribution=tfd.Normal(
        loc=mus,
        scale=sigmas
    )
)

x = np.linspace(-2,2,int(1000), dtype=np.double)
print(x.dtype)
pyx = gm.prob(x)
```

The result of `print(x.dtype)` is "dtype: 'float'"

As far as I know tensorflow does not have support for float datatypes as per [the documentation.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/DType)

For this reason I am especially confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to be a bug in the latest tensorflow-probability module. It only properly works with `float32`.

**WORKAROUND**

explicitly cast your parameters into `float32`

```
gm = tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
    mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(probs=alphas.astype('float32')),
    components_distribution=tfd.Normal(
        loc=mus.astype('float32'),
        scale=sigmas.astype('float32')
    )
)

x = np.linspace(-2,2,int(1000), dtype='float32')
pyx = gm.prob(x)
```

Comment: Reproducible colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1g37RztAguZHIPQqWOqvhe16XJDH0mPvz?usp=sharing

Comment: Ticket at tensorflow probability github: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/1010